# Vivado's removing used signals in vhdl

Tags: vhdl

Hi this code segment is from my top_module and some used signals in this part of code are removed. I wonder why and I need them to adjust what I call enable2. How can I do that??

```
[Synth 8-6014] Unused sequential element counter_for_enable2_reg was removed.  
[Synth 8-6014] Unused sequential element enable2_reg was removed.  
[Synth 8-6014] Unused sequential element c_cursor_pos_x_reg was removed.  
[Synth 8-6014] Unused sequential element c_cursor_pos_y_reg was removed.  
[Synth 8-6014] Unused sequential element address_rom_reg was removed.  
[Synth 8-6014] Unused sequential element address_rom_reg was removed.
```

---

```
Adjusting_enable2: process(rst,clk,cursor_pos_x,cursor_pos_y,enable,cursor_mode,current_cursor_mode,c_cursor_pos_x,c_cursor_pos_y) is
begin
if rst = '1' or (cursor_mode) /= (current_cursor_mode) or (c_cursor_pos_x /= cursor_pos_x) or (c_cursor_pos_y /= cursor_pos_y)  then

enable2 <= '1';
c_cursor_pos_x <= cursor_pos_x;
c_cursor_pos_y <= cursor_pos_y;
counter_for_enable2 <= 0;

elsif rising_edge(clk) then

if enable ='1' then

if counter_for_enable2 < PICTURE_WIDTH_HEIGHT*PICTURE_WIDTH_HEIGHT then

counter_for_enable2 <= counter_for_enable2 + 1;

else

enable2 <= '0';

end if;
end if;
end if;
end process;
```

Code may look awkward but enable2 is special enabling signal

I must also ask that is the reason for removing these signals that there are some hardware which can be used for the same purpose and not to increase hardware these signals are removed ?

Comment: Weird brackets: `or (cursor_mode) /= (current_cursor_mode)`

Comment: One last time : if you haven't verified this design in simulation before going on to synthesis, you're doing it the hard way. Most likely there is some error in the code, giving synth permission to trim these sitals because they don't do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @Humpawumpa says... if you aren't using counter_for_enable2 signal anywhere, which you aren't in this code snippet, it removes it (and anything contributing to it and nothing else) by default.  I think Vivado gives you a KEEP option, which is supposed to do just that and "keep" it, not optimize it out (ISE did).

Simple work-around/fix, if you aren't using the signal anywhere, but otherwise want to have it after synthesis for debug of your netlist sim, etc., assign it to an output port, and it will (should) keep it.

And, as @Oldfart says, Pretty sure your reset condition needs some parentheses-work.

Answer (score 2):

If the synthesizer says unused then it is quite likely the case that these signals are indeed unused. You may plan to use it for something, but as long as for the design it doesn't matter if they're there or not, the synthesizer simply removes them.
If everything is correct then it might be a bug... has been reported [here](https://forums.xilinx.com/t5/Synthesis/Many-spurious-quot-Synth-8-6014-Unused-sequential-element-was/m-p/769636#M21691)